# PHP and Python CLI programs start too slow for the first time (MacOS)

Tags: python, php, macos, command-line-interface

I work on Mac with Python and PHP.
From some period of time (I didn't notice exactly since when) all new scripts have started to launch very slowly.

I mean, even a simple hello-world program on Python or PHP works about 5-6 seconds for the first time. After the first launch, if NOT changing anything for the second time, the program works fast. But if changing even one letter in "hello world" string it compiles as long as it did for the first time.

I do remember that is wasn't like this before. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There are easily a million things which could be causing this, do you have any more information?

Comment: Have no idea which is to provide. Don't have a clue even from what to start...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP but for python3 I think I have a solution:

The slow initial startup seems to be related to python3 being bundelnd with Xcode. After installing Xcode calling python3 resolves to `/usr/bin/python3` which when called for the first time after reboot seems to check which python3 framework to use. (I'm not entirely sure what it really does though, but it seems to call Xcode-select for some reason?!?) This can take a very long time. Eventually it settles for calling a python3 framework from the Xcode installation e.g.

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3.9"

To circumvent this initial check I added a symlink to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3.9" under /usr/local/bin/python3

Since one cannot edit `/usr/bin` because of system protection this symlink has to go to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Then I made sure that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in my `$path` variable and now a call to python3 resolves to `/usr/local/bin/python3` which in turn directly resolves to the selected python3 framework from the Xcode installation.
One can use `ll $(which python3)` to check what gets called.

This now is again as fast as one can expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, run it as user `root`:

```
# ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
# ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```